# apache2 flask app css files cant be found?

Tags: python, html, css, flask, apache2

I've been trying to deploy a Flask app on apache2 but have problems serving css files. I am getting an 404 error files not found in the console after opening my app in the browser.

The folder structure is as followed:

```
/var/www/website/catalog.wsgi
/var/www/website/app/static/styles.css
```

The .conf file for apache is configured as followed:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName 18.130.209.7
    ServerAlias http://ec2-18-130-209-7.eu-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
    ServerAdmin admin@18.130.209.7
    WSGIDaemonProcess catalog python-path=/var/www/website:/var/www/website/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages
    WSGIProcessGroup catalog
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/website/catalog.wsgi
    <Directory /var/www/website/app/>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
    Alias /static /var/www/webstie/app/static
    <Directory /var/www/website/app/static/>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/website/app/api>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/website/app/auth>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/website/app/site>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/website/app/templates>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
    AliasMatch "(?i)^/([^/]+)/static/(.*)$" "/var/www///static/$2"
    <Directory "var/www/website/app/[^/]+/static/.*">
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

The import statement in index.html file looks like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='styles.css') }}" />
```

the following statement is included in the **init**.py file in the /app folder:

```
app.static_folder = 'static'
```

Any idea why the browser cant find the CSS files???
appreaciate all the help.

Answer (score 0):

There was a typo i did not noticed before in the .conf file:

```
Alias /static /var/www/webstie/app/static
```

fixed it to "website" now everything is working correctly.